# regex remove special character except first occurrence and last occurrence

Tags: python, regex

I need to remove the special characters inside angular brackets(<>)

```
date = "<dd_mm_yyyy>"
date_check_pattern= re.sub("[^A-Za-z<>]","",date)
```

But it is not working for

```
date = "<dd>_<mm>_<yyyy>"
#expected output <ddmmyyyy>
```

How to remove this angle bracket except first and last occurrence

Comment: Looks like something you need recursion. But you cannot match recursive patterns with built-in Python re, so you will have to pip install regex to install the PyPi regex module

Comment: What kind of special characters? Any character (except <>)? Or a certain subset?

Comment: @9769953 currently I am removing every other special character expect <>. Now I need to keep only first occurrence of  <  and last occurrence  of >. You can see  the  second scenario

Comment: Why not replace both the _ and <> characters, then surround the resulting string with <>. You can do that even with str.replace.

Comment: Again: what is a *special* character for you? You don't define "special".

Comment: @9769953 this date format is part of a file name so I can't do that eg: file_name<dd>_<mm>_<yyyy>.csv

Comment: Then you should specify that in your question better.

Comment: @vai_007 do you really have *filenames* that contain redirection characters? Are you misunderstanding some format specification perhaps, and the actual filename is `something_dd_mm_yyyy.csv` ? You can easily extract and parse that date

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Nope. File name will not consist of this things. But I have one string which stores the file name pattern. Here I am mentioning  this pattern.

Comment: You're trying to match those non-existent characters though. Post examples of the actual filenames. Parsing the date part is as simple as `datetime.strptime(filename[-14:-4],'%d_%m_%Y')`. The date part is extracted with `filename[-14:-4]` and parsed. If you wanted to remove the underscores you can use `filename[-14:-4].replace('_','')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match the whole string and capture what is between the `<` and `>`

Then do a second replacement removing all not allowed characters from the group 1 match in the first pattern.

The first pattern matches

- `<(.*?)>` Match from `<...>` and capture what is in between in group 1
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is to the right is

  - `[^\s<>]*$` Optionally match any char except `<` or `>` till the end of the string
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HVqczu/1)

The negated character class `[^A-Za-z0-9]+` in the second sub means matching 1+ times any character except what is listed in the character class.

Example code

```
import re

strings = [
    "<dd>_<mm>_<yyyy>",
    "<dd_mm_yyyy>",
    "<01>_<01>_<2022>",
    "file_name<dd>_<mm>_<yyyy>.csv",
    "file_name<01>_<01>_<2022>.csv",
    "file_name_<dd>_<mm>_<yyyy>_anything.csv"
]

for s in strings:
    print(
        re.sub(
            r'<(.*?)>(?=[^\s<>]*$)',
            lambda x: f"<{re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', x.group(1))}>",
            s
        )
    )
```

Output

```
<ddmmyyyy>
<ddmmyyyy>
<01012022>
file_name<ddmmyyyy>.csv
file_name<01012022>.csv
file_name_<ddmmyyyy>_anything.csv
```

Comment: From the comments it seems the strings are filenames. I suspect the OP confused the placeholders `<` and `>` for actual content

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Then you can make the pattern more specific. It all depends on  the context/placement of the parts in the string.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you it's worked. can u add some explanation in re.sub part that will be more helpful

Comment: @vai_007 I have added an explanation about the patterns to the answer.

Comment: @Thefourthbird this will not work for file_name_<dd>_<mm>_<yyyy>_anything.csv (something after last '>' )

Comment: @vai_007 Is there always either the end of the string or a space after `.csv`? Then it could be like this `<(.*?)>(?=[^\s<>]*$)` I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you want but if the characters always come at the start and the end of the line then you can use a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead to not match the characters at start or end

```py
import re

date = "<dd_mm_yyyy>"
date_check_pattern = re.sub("(?<!^)[^A-Za-z<>](?!$)","",date)
print(date_check_pattern)
```

output

```
<ddmmyyyy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do not use Regex for this. You can use the following function and also customize specialChar

```py
def removeSpecialChar(date):
    result = ""
    open = False
    specialChar = "_<>"
    index = 0

    lastClose = len(date)-date[::-1].find(">")-1 if date[::-1].find(">") != -1 else None
    if not lastClose: return date

    for c in date:
        if not open and c == "<":
            open = True
            result += c
        elif open and c == ">" and index==lastClose : open = False

        if open and c not in specialChar:
            result += c
        elif not open:
            result += c

        index+=1

    return result
```

**example**

```py
>>> removeSpecialChar("<dd>_<mm>_<yyyy>")
"<ddmmyyyy>"

>>> removeSpecialChar("Date: (<dd>_<mm>_<yyyy>)")
"Date: (<ddmmyyyy>)"
```